# How do you make napalm?

Tags: pyrotechnics, chemical-weapons

Not a recipe from movies, but actual napalm. I need it for a college experiment. I need the good kind preferably, but any recipe will suffice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the intention behind it seems rather dubious.

Answer (score 4):

The original meaning of napalm referred only to the thickener, not the flammable substance which it thickens, and not the mixture of the two.

> The aluminum soaps of this mixture of acids was christened "napalm" from "nap" for napthenic acids and "palm" for the coconut fatty acids.

Quoting from the 1951 article [They Don't Like "Hell Bombs"; Napalm + Gasoline = "Hell Bombs"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qOTlAAAAMAAJ&q=napalm&dq=napalm&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwCGoVChMI4Nq3kImdyQIVCMxjCh1iug8W), Armed Forces Chemical Journal, Volume 4, page 27

Coconut fatty acids include **palm**itic acid.

Also, from [THE SPECIFIC HEAT OF NAPALM–GASOLINE GELS](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/cjr49a-015) Canadian Journal of Research, 1949, 27a(4): 151-155, footnote 3:

> Napalm is a commercial product consisting of a basic aluminum soap of naphthenic, oleic, and palmitic acids in the approximate ratio of 1 : 1 : 2.